# How can I join two tables with condition in the joining variables Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am working in an Oracle Database. Suppose I have the next table (table 1):

| contract | key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| contract1 | abcdefghijklmn | NULL |
| contract2 | NULL | uhbgnd |

And the following table (table 2):

| key | key_value |
| --- | --- |
| abcdefghijklmn | 30 |
| 1234uhbgnd | 4 |

I want to join both of them by key of table2. As you can see, in table 1 I have the keys separated in two columns. In this case, what I want is to JOIN first by t2.key = t1.key1 and, if Key 1 is NULL, then the JOIN I would like is SUBSTR(t2.key, 5) = t1.key2.

In my mind, the JOIN would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.contract,
    t2.key,
    t2.key_value
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON CASE 
        WHEN t1.key1 IS NOT NULL THEN t2.key = t1.key1
        ELSE SUBSTR(t2.key, 5) = t1.key2
```

Thus, the desirable output would be:

| contract | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| contract1 | abcdefghijklmn | 30 |
| contract2 | 1234uhbgnd | 4 |

However, I cannot make this work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any answer involving a `CASE`/`DECODE` or set of `OR` conditions in a join is going to run into performance problems at large data volumes (unless Oracle rewrites the OR as a set of union, called "or-expansion". It cannot ever, however, rewrite a `CASE` statement).

You are far better off **joining twice** so each join can be a simple equijoin:

```
SELECT
    t1.contract,
    COALESCE(t2a.key,t2b.key) key,
    COALESCE(t2a.key_value,t2b.key_value) key_value
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2a ON t2a.key = t1.key1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2b ON SUBSTR(t2b.key, 5) = t1.key2
```

This assumes that `SUBSTR(t2.key,5)` is *unique*. If it is not, you would want to disable one of these joins to prevent them both from succeeding (as two one-to-many joins will give you a cartesian product). You can use conditional logic to do this, but keep it on the inner table columns *only*:

```
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2a ON t2a.key = DECODE(t1.key2,NULL,t1.key1)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2b ON SUBSTR(t2b.key, 5) = DECODE(t1.key1,NULL,t1.key2)
```

or if both can be non-null, pick one to favor:

```
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2a ON t2a.key = t1.key1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2b ON SUBSTR(t2b.key, 5) = DECODE(t1.key1,NULL,t1.key2)
```

These are still straight equijoins. The important thing is that while conditional logic on either one side or the other is acceptable, making the join operator itself (`=`) conditional or the whole clause conditional or referring to *both* tables within the same conditional clause or `CASE` statement creates significant problems for the optimizer. This is of course an issue only for joins; it is not a problem within the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: first, thanks for the answer. Secondly, could yo provide further explanations on why the second query you have provided would solve the problem when `SUBSTR(t2.key, 5)` is not unique? I lack the knowledge to see any difference between the two examples you have given.

Comment: @ShowMeTheWay, the decode (you could use case too) on the t1 columns will render it the t1 join key null if the other join is going to be used, ensuring no matches. That way only one join will find any rows in t2. It says, "if t1.key1 is null, then use t1.key2, otherwise null". And nothing equals a null. The goal is to prevent *both* joins from finding multiple rows in t2. This is unnecessary of the t2 join key is unique.

Comment: if I understand correctly, the DECODE would only work as expected if there were no such cases in which both `t1.key1` and `t1.key2` are informed, wouldn't it? If there are rows where both t1 keys are informed, then both JOINS would try to compare to a NULL value, wouldn't they? If I want to avoid those cases I would need to implement a CASE with a more complex and defined logic, am I right?

Comment: @ShowMeTheWay, that's right. you're getting into complex situations because of a data modelling mistake. Edited my answer with how to choose only one join to succeed in that situation. And in the future, avoid multiple join keys in a row like this. It causes query headaches.

Comment: thank you very much! You are right, the data modelling is quite a disaster, but until we solve it, we need to find workarounds like theone you have provided. Thak you very much once again :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can modify with OR.

```
SELECT
    t1.contract,
    t2.key,
    t2.key_value
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON (t1.key1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.key = t1.key1)
    OR (t1.key1 IS NULL AND SUBSTR(t2.key, 5) = t1.key2);
```

This query first checks if key1 is not NULL and joins on t2.key = t1.key1

Comment: "Oracle SQL doesn't allow you to use CASE directly in the ON clause of a join." Yes it does - a `CASE` expression returns a scalar value so the OP's syntax of trying to return an expression does not work but you certainly could return a scalar value from a `CASE` expression and use it in the `ON` clause of a join.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks. Some sources would be very helpful.

Comment: Try it and find out `SELECT * FROM DUAL d1 INNER JOIN DUAL d2 ON CASE d1.dummy WHEN 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = CASE d2.dummy WHEN 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4XGYSCw)

Comment: @MT0 So basically we can write the query in this way?
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON (CASE WHEN t1.key1 IS NOT NULL THEN t2.key ELSE SUBSTR(t2.key, 5) END) =
       (CASE WHEN t1.key1 IS NOT NULL THEN t1.key1 ELSE t1.key2 END);

Comment: Yes, I'd written that exact statement up as an answer (without the brackets) and then got called away and didn't hit post.

Comment: I was considering updating this answer with your information, but it is no longer necessary. :)

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value. If you want to do this with `CASE` expressions then evaluate the left-hand side and right-hand side in different `CASE` expressions so that each returns a scalar value:

```sql
SELECT t1.contract,
       t2.key,
       t2.key_value
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON CASE
          WHEN t1.key1 IS NOT NULL
          THEN t2.key
          ELSE SUBSTR(t2.key, 5)
          END
        = CASE
          WHEN t1.key1 IS NOT NULL
          THEN t1.key1
          ELSE t1.key2
          END;
```

Alternatively, use `AND` and `OR`.